# Is my calculation correct?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

For $\Omega=C_{\beta} \subset \mathbb{R^2}$ and $\beta \in(0,2\pi)$

define   $$C_{\beta}=\left\{(r\cos(\phi),r\sin(\phi))\in\mathbb{R^2}|0<r<1,|\phi|<\frac{1}{2}\beta\right\}$$
and
$\hspace{3.85cm}u(r\cos(\phi),r\sin(\phi))=\frac{\beta^2}{9\beta^2-\pi^2}(r^3-r^{\frac{\pi}{\beta}})\cos(\frac{\pi}{\beta}\phi)$ .

Then $ u \notin C^2( \overline {C_{\beta}}). $

My approach is calculating the partial differentiations :

$u_r(r\cos(\phi),r\sin(\phi))=\frac{\beta^2}{9\beta^2-\pi^2}(3r^2-\frac{\pi}{\beta}r^{\frac{\pi}{\beta}-1})\cos(\frac{\pi}{\beta}\phi) $

$u_{rr}(r\cos(\phi),r\sin(\phi))=\frac{\beta^2}{9\beta^2-\pi^2}(6r-\frac{\pi}{\beta}(\frac{\pi}{\beta}-1)r^{\frac{\pi}{\beta}-2})\cos(\frac{\pi}{\beta}\phi)$

one sees that there is a problem in the origin , if $\beta>\frac{\pi}{2}$

and  $u_{\phi\phi} \in C(\overline C_\beta) $

Thanks for your answer .

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Is my calculation right ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3193961/is-my-calculation-right)

Comment: yes , you are right , still there is no answer

Comment: Your initial question was asked only 18 hours ago, be patient. Someone will eventually come over and answer your question. It is not recommended to repost an exact duplicate of your own question it will very likely be closed as a duplicate and it is also seen as rude to do so. If you wish for your question to gain more attention you can simply edit your original post (perhaps to make it more clear !).